# How do I store object as a radio input value in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have an array of objects like below :

```
const plans = [{type:'2'},{type:'3'},{type:'1'}]
```

And I want to store those values into radio inputs in Vue. I've tried this :

```
<input type="radio" v-model="pick" :value="plans[0]" />
<input type="radio" v-model="pick" :value="plans[1]" />
<input type="radio" v-model="pick" :value="plans[2]" />
```

But instead I got an error :

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String,
> Number, got Object

Is there any way I can do to hack this? Thank you

Comment: Your array is not valid, it's an array of objects but an object is a pair of key/value. Here you only have a value. So, remove the object and keep it as simple strings. Hence the prop error: it expects a string or a number but you give it a wrong kind of object.

Comment: oh my bad i maybe have too simplified the example. It's actually just a normal array of objects. it's just me trying to make it simple. I'll edit the question

Comment: You need to have it as `plans[1].type` so. But you still have the error on a prop, which one is it?

Comment: @kissu I want to like store the whole object as value. Is it not possible? I've seen a case in angular and seems like angular can do it.

Comment: It's not Angular here but Vue. What is the prop error'ing?

Comment: Let's say my default `pick` value is empty object. Once I clicked any radio button, the value will be filled with the object according to the clicked button. So my `pick` data is should be like `pick = {type:'2'}`

Comment: Here it's a radio and not a checkbox. I recommend reading the documentation about radio buttons: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#radio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247864/discussion-between-ilmi-and-kissu).

Comment: This should be working. Here is a working example: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqFUctOwzAQ/BXLl4DUxBRukRuJL4ADt7qHNNmAS/yQ7aRCkf+ddfpUkcptdmZ3xt6d6Ku1xTgALSn3jZM2EA9hsJXQUlnjApmIg45E0jmjSIatmdBCN0b7QKxsvqElq9TykL1pyB7PUl9rj8p6Cj8Wyuw5i4sjfLnAZRY3QnN2iMZQLAIoHA6AFSG8lWP1PseUZJpOiTFylpQ0IAKX2g6BJMuVoK5upRGUyBYLowFhOdb9kLT5VeunDXJjrkwLfSJnT6RY8gu8r7fQk86403yFP+Nspv9PDPsEbxKXdxLxk9eJ83z1sTeXRM7OO6ELerhLrmpb7LzReLkpmYij4AXFTSUmcXivVAv6FYL1JWO+a9K9d74w7pMhKtygg1RQgFf51pm9B4fGgi6uPBiSI7jcgW7BgbvnedP6xzfZRqEjjb/Y8NxG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      pick: null,
      plans: [{type:'2'}, {type:'3'}, {type:'1'}]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="item in plans" :key="item.type">
    <input type="radio" v-model="pick" :value="item" />
    <label>{{ item.type }}</label>
  </div>
  {{ pick }}
</div>
```

Comment: Don't suggest using the index as a key, it's doing the opposite.